# Convert the column type from string to datetime format in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I was trying to convert the String in DateTime datatype. I was having four columns similar they got changed in the DateTime datatype. But for this particular column, it was showing me the below error

```
DateParseError: Invalid date specified (71/23)
```

[image]

In this format, I was using  the code that I was using for the conversion:

```
DOB_Permits["job_start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(DOB_Permits["job_start_date"])
```

Comment: Make sure all the values in that columns are in the correct format. Check for null values as well

Comment: Hey! previous columns were containing the null values which got executed fine but similarly doing on this particular column it is showing me the error.

Comment: If you look at the error closely, It says 71/23 is the invalid date specified. Try to look into the data and see where this leads to

Comment: Hey! @Lokesh,
It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error was resolved with the below code, as there was some mismatch in the format of the date.

```
DOB_Permits["job_start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(DOB_Permits["job_start_date"], errors='coerce', format="%y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own apply method as well using the datetime library in Python.

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_to_date(date_string):
   fmt = '%d/%m/%Y' # Choose fmt according to your format
   try:
      return datetime.strp(date_string, fmt)
   except ValueError:
      return 'Invalid Date'

DOB_Permits["job_start_date"] = DOB_Permits["job_start_date"].apply(lambda x: convert_to_date(x))
```